# Binding string response(with HTMLTags) to iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, jersey, jersey-client

I make a ajax call to rest endpoint which returns HTML tags as a string response. Now I need to bind this to iframe.

Here data has html tags like

```
var data="<html><head><title>iFram</title></head><body>hi</body></html>"
```

I have tried `document.getElementById('iframeid').src=data`

also I have tried

```
$('#iframeid').contents().find("html").append(data);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

finally we have got the solution with iframe attribute "srcdoc" which 
we used like `document.getElementById('iframeid').srcdoc=data;`