# Select text adjacent to element using xpath

Tags: html, xpath, expression

I'm begginer to write xpath expression,facing an issue for captureing string (or) text of next to the `<b>` Tag sibling element like,

```
<div id="product-desc" class="green-box">
    <p class="ref">
        <b class="">Mfr Part#:</b>
        "STM6520AQRRDG9F"
        <br class="">
        <b class="">Mounting Method:</b>
        "Surface Mount"
        <br class="">
        <b class="">Package Style:</b>
        "TDFN-8"
        <br class="">
        <b class="">Packaging:</b>
        "REEL"
        <br class="">    
    </p>
 </div>
```

In Above html code how should i get the text xpath expression  i.e ("STM6520AQRRDG9F") next to `<b>` element.I tried with following ways

```
//*[@id="product-desc"]/p[2]/b[1]/following-sibling::text()
```

can any one suggest me to get currect xpath expression of getting text xapth Expression.

Thanks for advance regards.

Comment: it should be `p[1]` ...

Comment: The title of your question is utterly unhelpful - it could be the title of any question that is related to XPath. Please find a more meaningful title.

Comment: I changed the title.

Answer (score 2):

As hek2mgl has mentioned, the text you'd like to find is in the *first* `p` element of that `div`. Also, to avoid any surprising results, you should select only the first following text node that is a sibling.

One way to do it is

```
//*[@id="product-desc"]/p[1]/b[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

and the result will be

```
[EMPTY LINE]
"STM6520AQRRDG9F"
[EMPTY LINE]
```

Comment: thanks for spot reply ,I have tried with your xpath expression it got working ....   thanks Mathias Müller.

Comment: @user3008819 Please do not forget to [**accept this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem. Thanks! And by the way, you could also accept your own answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25264529/1987598).